# flasgger-flask-swagger: request parameters not displayed in Webpage

Tags: flask, swagger, flasgger

I want to create a REST API using flask. I also would like to document the api using swagger 2.0. This is the reason why I chose flasgger to create a webpage for the documentation. Right now the web page is rendered but the parameters for the request are not displayed, although I did add them in the yaml file.
I added the result of the webpage as image.
Part of the content of the yaml file can be seen in the other image.
In the main file I configured the Swagger object like in the image below.
I would be really thankful, if you could help find the reason why, I am not able to see those parameters.

[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAiMt.png)

[documentation file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOSRW.png)

[webpage result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iXEF.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your view with the decorator `@swag_from("your_yaml_file_here")`

for example:

```
from flasgger import swag_from

@app.route('/colors/<palette>/')
@swag_from('colors.yml')
def colors(palette):
    ....
```

If you do not want to use the decorator you can use the docstring `file:` shortcut.

```
@app.route('/colors/<palette>/')
def colors(palette):
    """
    file: colors.yml
    """
    ...
```

Refer the link https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger to know more.